# How to debug channels efficiently in Phoenix?

Tags: phoenix-framework

When something raises in Request/Response mode, we have a nice html page with the stack trace and the code that causes the problem.

When something raises in a Channel, the only way to know what happened is looking at the console, which displays an obscure inspect of some Struct.

Is there a way to format this output nicely ?